# Writing a macro

Tags: c++, macros, c++11, c-preprocessor

How I'm suppose to implement a macro that would do something like this:
//pseudocode

```
#define CHOOSE(X) if(X) expand to "" and if !X expand to return nullptr;
```

**Edit**

```
template<class SomePolicy>
struct M
{

template<class Policy = SomePolicy>
typename std::enable_if<IsThrow<Policy>::value,void>::type fnc()
{
}

template<class Policy = SomePolicy>
typename std::enable_if<!IsThrow<Policy>::value,std::nullptr_t>::type fnc()
{
    return nullptr;
}
};
```

**@All_WHO_TRIED_TO_HELP_ME** Hey Guys I want to thank you very much for your priceless help. It couldn't be done without you. Thanks to all of you. Thank you.

Comment: Is it true that `CHOOSE(X)` is `""` or `return nullptr`. No `return` word in the first case?

Comment: @GMan your example looks great, but I'm getting an error that it cannot convert const char* to nullptr;

Comment: Didn't we show you how to solve this in the last question? You have to make two functions and call the correct one based on different types.

Comment: @Alexey the point is that it depends entirely on policy if this fnc will return or not;

Comment: @GMan no, because in the last question both fncs were returning void.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to edit section. 
Use the fact that expression `return g();` is valid even if `g` return `void`.

```
template <class T> T GetDefault() { return T(); }
template <> void GetDefault<void>() {  } // special case for void
```

and use

```
return GetDefault<void>();
```

or

```
return GetDefault<std::nullptr_t>();
```

Comment: It looks like this may be the way to go but it gives me an error: Error 1 error C2662: 'T M<SomePolicy>::GetDefault<nullptr>(void)' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const M<SomePolicy>' to 'M<SomePolicy> &'

Comment: `GetDefault<nullptr>` is wrong. You need `GetDefault<std::nullptr_t>`.

Comment: Hey man it works. I would really want to thank you for your answer. Most appreciated. Thank you. Wow I can't f....ing believe it. Great. Wonderful weekend ahead of me and my project. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to implement macros if you have C++ !

What do you want to do exactly ???

Comment: Wrong with it is you're using the deprecated conversion from string literal to `char*`. :) `const char*` would be good.

Comment: Qualification - macros have their place in C++, but this is not it.

Comment: NULL is from C, BTW; the OP is somehow right to use `nullptr` (keyword from the new standard).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a macro, use an inline function.  I am not sure what it would return in this case but that's an issue either way.

Comment: due to a horrible overlook by C++ commitee I cannot use def. args in fnc <>. If I could I would do something like this: Check my edit. But I can't and instead of having nice and elegant code I have to do tricks like this. I do not want to specialize this class by enable_if for the fact that I do not want to maintain two versions of almost identical classes.

Comment: I guess the question is, what is `X` here?  if this is a template question that's certainly not clear, hence the so far unhelpful answers.

Comment: X is a boolean value calculated from a <> param

Answer (score 0):

```
#define CHOOSE(X) (return(X)?"":nullptr)
```